# I want to merge an object with its texture

Tags: mesh

I have an object that have really great detail. but When i export it to print on a 3d printer I lose all the great detail. How Do I merge the obj and the texture file to make them one single mesh? It comes with the object ,base color,height,metallic,mixed_AO,Normal_DirectX,roughness. I am used to working with Daz3s studio So I know most of these. So the normal_Directx with be depth of the  details. I am not sure on how to bake or rather fuse the normal to the object file in a way that I can export it as an stl file to print

Comment: *"have really great detail"*, "*lose all the great detail*" are highly subjective definitions. What exactly details, how are they created.. I can only guess you ask about [bringing details made with microdisplacement into real one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McALCOr39rY) and it's generally possible though can be a bit computational heavy due to usage of openEXR files to avoid values clamping

Comment: We don't know how you are setting up your materials or the topology of your object, or if you are using normal or bump maps or displacement modifiers to achieve what you call *"really great detail"*... in short, all we know is whatever you share. Please edit your question and add more information.